# Конвертирование даты гг-мм-дд из формы в таблицу в виде дд-мм-гггг

Tags: php, html, sql

Имеется форма с `input` типа date в количестве 2 штук(dtarrive,dtdepart) формат этих полей дд-мм-гг т.к. База хранит в формате гг-мм-дд необходимо сконвертировать в формат дд-мм-гг.

```
INSERT INTO tbooking(dtarrive, dtdepart, userid) VALUES (LOWER(DATE_FORMAT("20-12-2017",'%d-%m-%Y')), LOWER(DATE_FORMAT(22-12-2017,"%d-%m-%Y")),"777")
```

В таком виде и в различных вариациях дата ставится 0000-00-00.
Поле в БД тип DATE.

Comment: База хранит в формате ГГГГ-ММ-ДД

Comment: Если Вам помог один из ответов, Вы не стесняйтесь, укажите что ответ Вам помог!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STR_TO_DATE () преобразует строку в указанные значения даты на основе строки формата FMT. Функция STR_TO_DATE () может возвращать дату, время или значение DATETIME, основываясь на входных и формата строк. Если входная строка не является корректной, функция STR_TO_DATE () возвращает NULL.

```
INSERT INTO tbooking SET dtarrive= STR_TO_DATE("20-12-2017", '%d-%m-%Y'),
dtdepart= STR_TO_DATE("20-12-2017", '%d-%m-%Y'), userid = "777"
```

Документация доступна по [ссылке](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-str_to_date-function.php).

Выбор поля в database:

В Вашем случае следует выбрать Date, если дата и время DateTime. Документацию можете почитать по [ссылке](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/DATETIME.html).

Comment: В таком случае, input-поле должно быть типом text а не date, тогда нужно будет календарь реализовывать другим путем?

Comment: Никак нет! Это Вам для примера, на view в input делайте type="date", а в модели подставляете value из Вашего input: dtarrive= STR_TO_DATE('" . $valueFromInput . "', '%d-%m-%Y')

Comment: Все работает, я у себя проверил, все что Вам осталось сделать - это взять значение из input и положить его в запрос.

Comment: С работы приеду проверю, спасибо! И еще вопрос в базе поле dtarrive dtdepart Varchar тип ставить? Или тип Date понимает такой формат?

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Если ответ Вам помог, Вы можете выбрать его как верный!)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста! Подтверждайте!)

Comment: Еще момент в PHP mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbooking(hotelid, roomid, dtarrive, dtdepart, userid, bookingcode, price, status) VALUES (".$hotelid.",".$roomid.", STR_TO_DATE('".$dtarrive."','%d-%m-%Y'), STR_TO_DATE('".$dtdepart."','%d-%m-%Y'),".$userid.", UUID(), ".$price.",".$status.")"); не срабатывает на UPDATE тоже, echo вывожу  вижу STR_TO_DATE('10-10-2017','%d-%m-%Y') но в базе показывает нули, в случае insert просто не садится

Comment: Думаю Вы не сможете так вывести, потому что STR_TO_DATE это функция MySQL(начиная с 4й версии). UPDATE это уже другая задача, я уже не на работе, но по памяти Вам  просто следует заменить из первого запроса INSERT INTO на UPDATE.

Comment: почитайте доки: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-str_to_date-function.php

Comment: Все получилось, вдруг кому пригодится: 
$timearrive = strtotime($dtarrive);
$timedepart = strtotime($dtdepart);
$newformatarrive = date('d-m-y',$timearrive);
$newformatdepart = date('d-m-y',$timedepart);
и потом это в Update и Insert

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, не надо писать в запросе вместо даты арифметическое выражение
Во-вторых, дата имеет формат ГГГГ-ММ-ДД
В-третьих, для преобразования форматов в мускуле есть функция STR_TO_DATE
В-четвертых, для вставки надо использовать подготовленные выражения

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbooking(dtarrive, dtdepart, userid) 
        VALUES (STR_TO_DATE(?,'%d-%m-%y'), STR_TO_DATE(?,'%d-%m-%y'), ?)";
$pdo->prepare($sql)->execute(['12-12-16','12-01-17', 777]);
```